# How to check file on network drive on Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a network drive location, and I want to check if the file exist.
Windows explore shows:

```
\\Netapp-xx\updates\xyz\abc.sh
```

I have tried:

```
//Netapp-xx/updates/xyz/abc.sh
/Netapp-xx/updates/xyz/abc.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="\\Netapp-xx\updates\xyz\abc.sh"

if [ -f $dir ]; then
  echo "File exists"
else
  echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

I got "File does not exists". It supposes to give "File exists" since the file is there.

Comment: Are you running this `bash` on windows using `Git Bash`? `Cygwin`? `Wsl`? or is this another computer entirely?

Comment: I am running the script in bash. 
The \\Netapp-xx\updates\xyz\abc.sh is on a shared network.

Comment: `bash` is a shell. It's a shell that can be run in your operating system (linux) or inside a program on windows that mimics a linux environment like `wsl`, `cygwin`, or `git bash`. Where is this being run. Does the computer upon which it's being run have this remote storage attached somehow (like a mapped network drive in windows or an NFS mount in linux)? It's not clear at all what kind of remote file system this is or what connectivity has been made to it on your computer.

Comment: JNeill, I'll try to explain what it is. The \\Netapp-xx\updates\xyz\abc.sh is on a company shared network. I could access it via my desktop machine.
The script is on a dedicated Ubuntu machine, connected to the same switch as desktop machine. I am not sure if it's attached to mapped network drive or NFS. How do I find out? This might be the cause my script won't recognize the "dir=..." so it give else clause.

Comment: are you able to ls the contents of any of the folders on the remote device from your bash prompt? I would expect forward slashes to be the correct syntax.

Comment: Right. I think that's the big question now. You are sitting on an Ubuntu machine in a bash shell and you are trying to hit this remote script on a remote file system of unknown type. I think you'll have to solve that unknown before you can move forward. If there is a more ephemeral connection available to the server that is hosting that file like `ftp` or `sftp` or `scp` then perhaps that's an option. Otherwise if it's a windows share then you may need to do some research to see how to mount a windows share to your linux ubuntu box.

Comment: Gem, no I cannot ls that \\Netapp-xx\.....
JNevill, I just googled search. Mount is what I need based on suggestion. Can you confirm that?

Comment: OK guys, I found the problem is. I need to mount first before I could use it. 
mount -t cifs $mountpoint $mountdir username=xxx,password=yyy,ver=1.0